# RDF: How can I link a schema.org:travelaction:agent:organization to a health-lifesci.schema.org:MedicalBusiness subcategory?

Tags: html, rdf, schema.org

I have a situation like that:

```
<div prefix='schema: http://schema.org/ health-lifesci: https://health-lifesci.schema.org' typeof='schema:TravelAction'>
...  
  <div property='schema:agent' typeof='health-lifesci:Dermatology'>
    <meta property='schema:name' content='My Doctor' />
...
  </div>
</div>
```

`Dermatology` is a `MedicalBusiness` which is an `Organization`. This is shown in the [relevant page](http://schema.org/docs/full.html) of schema.org.

However, the [structured data tool](https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool) recognizes it as `Thing`.

```
agent

   @type        Thing

   name         My Doctor
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Schema.org extensions, like [health-lifesci](http://health-lifesci.schema.org/), also use the core namespace `http://schema.org/`.

Each term from an extension lists its canonical URI that should be used. On http://health-lifesci.schema.org/Dermatology it says:

> Canonical URL: http://schema.org/Dermatology

So your HTML+RDFa should be:

```html
<div prefix='schema: http://schema.org/' typeof='schema:TravelAction'>
  <div property='schema:agent' typeof='schema:Dermatology'>
    <meta property='schema:name' content='My Doctor' />
  </div>
</div>
```

However, the [`Dermatology` type](http://health-lifesci.schema.org/Dermatology) is not an expected value for the [`agent` property](http://schema.org/agent). It expects an `Organization` or `Person` value, but `Dermatology` is neither; it’s a [`MedicalSpecialty`](http://health-lifesci.schema.org/MedicalSpecialty) enumeration value.

(I’m not sure why `Dermatology` is listed as sub-type of [`MedicalBusiness`](http://health-lifesci.schema.org/MedicalBusiness), but without listing this as parent on [its page](http://health-lifesci.schema.org/Dermatology).)

Comment: (I created an issue: [Dermatology is a MedicalSpecialty, but listed as sub-type of MedicalBusiness](https://github.com/schemaorg/schemaorg/issues/1500).)